# Setting subquery to variable to be used within the IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I would like to use a variable to represent a result set that will be used in the WHERE clause of a query.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE 
  Exam1_ID IN (SELECT Id FROM Exam) 
  OR Exam2_ID IN (SELECT Id FROM Exam) 
  OR Exam3_ID IN (SELECT Id FROM Exam) 
  OR Exam4_ID IN (SELECT Id FROM Exam)
```

I would like to use a variable in place of `SELECT Id FROM Exam` so I don't have to keep repeating the query. I tried declaring a variable but since the results of the subquery could contain multiple integers I am not sure what the declare the variable as. I went ahead and tried ...

```
DECLARE @SubQuery INT;
SET @SubQuery = (SELECT Id FROM Exam);

SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE 
    Exam1_ID IN (@SubQuery) 
    OR Exam2_ID IN (@SubQuery) 
    OR Exam3_ID IN (@SubQuery) 
    OR Exam4_ID IN (@SubQuery)
```

I received the following error ..

`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: Have you tried declaring that variable as a table rather than a single value?

Comment: You declared your variable as an INT, and that's literally what it is *an* (singular) int, so it cannot hold more than one value. To do what you want to do, you could concatenate the values into a `varchar`, and use dynamic sql (there are simpler solutions though, like Rich Benner's solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an exists like this.

```
      SELECT *
        FROM Table1 t1
        WHERE EXISTS (  
        SELECT 1  FROM Exam e 
        WHERE e.Id in ( t1.Exam1_ID , t1.Exam2_ID , t1.Exam3_ID, t1.Exam4_ID ) 
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably find that this performs better using a `WHERE EXISTS` like this

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT * 
                FROM Exam e 
                WHERE t1.Exam1_ID = e.Id
                OR t1.Exam2_ID = e.Id
                OR t1.Exam3_ID = e.Id
                OR t1.Exam4_ID = e.Id)
```

Comment: And make even prettier with `WHERE e.Id IN (Exam1_ID, Exam2_ID, ...)`

Answer (score 2):

Lets begin from error message

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

The reason is pretty simple, you declared your `subquery` as `INT`
So if you will change it to `TABLE(Id INT)` you will receive new error message.

You can use different ways to solve your problem.

1) Inner join (It can give you duplicates, so I dont know is it valid for you to use this method)

```
DECLARE @SubQuery TABLE (RecordId INT)

INSERT INTO 
    @SubQuery
SELECT 
    Id
FROM 
    Exam

SELECT * 
FROM 
   Table1 t1
INNER JOIN @Subquery sq 
  ON sq.Id = t1.Exam1_ID
    OR sq.Id = t1.Exam2_ID
    OR sq.Id = t1.Exam3_ID
    OR sq.Id = t1.Exam4_ID
```

2) Exist

Please find sample in Rich Benner answer. He posted it while I was typing. But I found one typo there, he used different aliases in exists block

```
 OR t1.Exam2_ID = e.Id --t1 - correct alias
 OR t2.Exam2_ID = e.Id --t2 - incorrect
 OR t3.Exam2_ID = e.Id --t3 - incorrect
 OR t4.Exam2_ID = e.Id --t4 - incorrect
```